# Issue when uninstalling dattobd-dkms

Tags: kernel, uninstall, dkms

```
Configurazione di dattobd-dkms (0.10.15-29.1ubuntu20.04)...
Removing old dattobd-0.10.15 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.10.15
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new dattobd-0.10.15 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-29-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-29-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/dattobd-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-29-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto dattobd-dkms (--configure):
 il sottoprocesso installato pacchetto dattobd-dkms script post-installation ha restituito lo stato di errore 10
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 dattobd-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And this is the crash log:

```
$ cat /var/crash/dattobd-dkms.0.crash                    
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for dattobd-0.10.15 for kernel 5.8.0-29-generic (x86_64)
 mer 25 nov 2020, 16:44:53, CET
 make: ingresso nella directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-29-generic»
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.o
 In file included from ./include/linux/umh.h:4,
                  from ./include/linux/kmod.h:9,
                  from ./include/linux/module.h:16,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/includes.h:10,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:7:
 /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c: In function ‘__tracer_setup_snap’:
 ./include/linux/gfp.h:297:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘blk_alloc_queue’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   297 | #define GFP_KERNEL (__GFP_RECLAIM | __GFP_IO | __GFP_FS)
       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       |                    |
       |                    unsigned int
 /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:3574:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘GFP_KERNEL’
  3574 |  dev->sd_queue = blk_alloc_queue(GFP_KERNEL);
       |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/includes.h:12,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:7:
 ./include/linux/blkdev.h:1174:55: note: expected ‘blk_qc_t (*)(struct request_queue *, struct bio *)’ {aka ‘unsigned int (*)(struct request_queue *, struct bio *)’} but argument is of type ‘unsigned int’
  1174 | struct request_queue *blk_alloc_queue(make_request_fn make_request, int node_id);
       |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:3574:18: error: too few arguments to function ‘blk_alloc_queue’
  3574 |  dev->sd_queue = blk_alloc_queue(GFP_KERNEL);
       |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/includes.h:12,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:7:
 ./include/linux/blkdev.h:1174:23: note: declared here
  1174 | struct request_queue *blk_alloc_queue(make_request_fn make_request, int node_id);
       |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:3583:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘blk_queue_make_request’; did you mean ‘blk_queue_max_segments’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  3583 |  blk_queue_make_request(dev->sd_queue, snap_mrf);
       |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       |  blk_queue_max_segments
 /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c: In function ‘agent_init’:
 /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:5165:51: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  5165 |  info_proc = proc_create(INFO_PROC_FILE, 0, NULL, &dattobd_proc_fops);
       |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       |                                                   |
       |                                                   const struct file_operations *
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/includes.h:16,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:7:
 ./include/linux/proc_fs.h:107:122: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct file_operations *’
   107 | struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent, const struct proc_ops *proc_ops);
       |                                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.o] Errore 1
 make: *** [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build] Errore 2
 make: uscita dalla directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-29-generic»
DKMSKernelVersion: 5.8.0-29-generic
Date: Wed Nov 25 16:44:56 2020
DuplicateSignature: dkms:dattobd-dkms:0.10.15-29.1ubuntu20.04:/var/lib/dkms/dattobd/0.10.15/build/dattobd.c:3574:18: error: too few arguments to function ‘blk_alloc_queue’
Package: dattobd-dkms 0.10.15-29.1ubuntu20.04
PackageVersion: 0.10.15-29.1ubuntu20.04
SourcePackage: dattobd-dkms
Title: dattobd-dkms 0.10.15-29.1ubuntu20.04: dattobd kernel module failed to build
```

Comment: The package is incompatible with the kernel. You have th `5.8`, but Ubuntu 20.04 has the `5.4`. And it looks like you are trying to install it, not to uninstall.

Comment: dattobd-dkms is listed in the installed packages. And I can't uninstall it. I need to remove it.

Comment: Run `sudo apt purge dattobd-dkms`

Comment: that gives the errors above

Comment: Boot with a 5.4  kernel. I can't get why it is trying to build. Any way the problem is with the kernel version. You installed a new kernel probably by `linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` or another way.

Comment: I didn't. The only kernel in my system is 5.8
Never had 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall after deleting the following files.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dattobd-dkms.prerm

This issue is fixed with the code below.
https://github.com/elastio/elastio-snap

Comment: This answer does not explain why to delete that file, or have any explanation.

Comment: It looks like this is a pre-removal script that runs before dattobd-dkms is removed. Renaming/removing it worked for me. Mine had the following contents:

`#!/bin/bash -e


if [ "$1" = "remove" ] || [ "$1" = "purge" ]; then

    lsmod | grep dattobd >& /dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

        modprobe -r dattobd || :

    fi

fi



dkms status -m dattobd -v 0.11.7 | grep dattobd >& /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

    dkms remove -m dattobd -v 0.11.7 --all

fi`